# optimize lock-free code of passing stock market index to other threads

Tags: c#, real-time, hft

I am calculating stock market index which changes so ofthen that I've decided to give it separate "core" (one of 24 virtual available cores) of my server (running 2 * E5-2640)  cause anyway so far I have only 5% of CPU load so I have a lot of free CPU power available.

As I need asap reaction to stock market index change I've decided to use lock-free code. This is example of what I'm going to use in real life:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestBlockingCollection2
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            int i = 0;

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Adding " + (i + 1));
                    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    i++;
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                      {
                int prevI = 0;
                while (true)
                {
                    if (prevI < i)
                    {
                        sw.Stop();
                        long microseconds = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L));
                        Console.WriteLine("Received " + i + ". Spent " + microseconds + " microseconds.");
                        prevI = i;
                    }
                }
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\bin\testBlockingCollection2>TestBlockingCollection2.exe
Adding 1
Received 1. Spent 1 microseconds.
Adding 2
Received 2. Spent 5 microseconds.
Adding 3
Received 3. Spent 2 microseconds.
Adding 4
Received 4. Spent 2 microseconds.
Adding 5
Received 5. Spent 2 microseconds.
Adding 6
Received 6. Spent 4 microseconds.
Adding 7
Received 7. Spent 2 microseconds.
Adding 8
Received 8. Spent 2 microseconds.
Adding 9
Received 9. Spent 5 microseconds.
Adding 10
Received 10. Spent 2 microseconds.
Adding 11
Received 11. Spent 2 microseconds.
Adding 12
Received 12. Spent 2 microseconds.
Adding 13
Received 13. Spent 2 microseconds.
Adding 14
Received 14. Spent 2 microseconds.
Adding 15
Received 15. Spent 2 microseconds.
Adding 16
Received 16. Spent 3 microseconds.
Adding 17
Received 17. Spent 5 microseconds.
Adding 18
Received 18. Spent 2 microseconds.
Adding 19
Received 19. Spent 2 microseconds.
```

Having 2 microseconds in average is pretty amazing comparing to 18 microseconds that I have using `BlockingCollection` [what better do we have to asynchronous execute method than BlockingCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267850/what-better-do-we-have-to-asynchronous-execute-method-than-blockingcollection)

And I really want this microseconds as I have a lot of free CPU power and in HFT microseconds are important.

So the question is easy - do you see any problems with my example? I was not ever wrote lock-free code so I guess I may do stupid mistakes. I do not use spinlocks, as I assume primitive change (int/double/decimal) is "atomic" and so in the second thread I always receive either previous or new value but nothing else.

I.e. if in one thread I'm changing int x from 100 to 555, in second thread I will either have 100 or 555, but never 500 or 155 or anything else.

Comment: Main problem I see is, this code doesn't do the calculation, it just increments an integer. So, its simple to avoid the use of locks. Until you have to access state there is no real issue.

Comment: You should proably do `Interlocked.Increment` instead of `++`

Comment: @Jodrell in real application i will calculate `double` index and at receive side I just plan to test if it changed comparing to previous value. The problem with this code is probably that it uses to much CPU. If i can save CPU time saving perfomances (2 mcs) at the same time?

Comment: So, you are concerned primarily with how quickly you respond to a change in `i` or the index?

Comment: @Jodrell yes, i have several consumers in different threads which should react quickly when index `double` value is changed. I've used `int` in example for simplification.

Comment: Have you tried, `Monitor.PulseAll` and `Monitor.Wait`?

Comment: @Jodrell now but I guess this would be slower because BlockingCollection must be using something like that.

Comment: Never guess what is slower/faster.